# Why does the output of animation.FuncAnimation have to be bound to a name?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider this code [taken](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html) from the matplotlib website which animates 
a sine curve moving to the right.

```
    """
    A simple example of an animated plot
    """
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.animation as animation

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
    line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))


    def animate(i):
        line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i/10.0))  # update the data
        return line,


    # Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
    def init():
        line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
        return line,

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init, interval=25, blit=True)

    # Commenting out the previous line, and uncommenting the following line gives a static image. 
   #animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init, interval=25, blit=True)
    plt.show()
```

This code is identical to the one I linked on Matplotlib, except for the 
two commented lines before `plt.show()`. Notice that after binding the output of `animation.FuncAnimation()` to the name `ani`, this name is not used anywhere in the arguments to `plt.show()`!

So thinking that this binding was redundant, I deleted the `ani=` part. 
The result was that I got a static image. As long as the output of `animation.FuncAnimation` is bound to *something* the animation works as expected. Otherwise not.

what is happening here?

I am using Python 2.7.11 (Anaconda distribution) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I expanded my answer to the duplicate a bit.

Comment: @Ajean Good catch, I was about to re-write that answer because I did not remember writing the other one ;)

Comment: @tcaswell Thank you so much! That really helped!